# Memoization with Vavr seems incosistent

Tags: java, vavr

When the function is defined as following

```
static Function1<BigInteger, BigInteger> fibonacci = Function((BigInteger value) ->
            value.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) ? BigInteger.ZERO
                    : value.equals(BigInteger.ONE) ? BigInteger.ONE
                    : value.equals(BigInteger.valueOf(2)) ? BigInteger.ONE
                    : Program.fibonacci.apply(value.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).add(Program.fibonacci.apply(value.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(2))))
    ).memoized();
```

And called

```
System.out.println(fibonacci.apply(BigInteger.valueOf(1000)));
```

It calculated very fast. However if I move the `memoized()` to function variable as follows

```
static Function1<BigInteger, BigInteger> fibonacci = Function((BigInteger value) ->
            value.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) ? BigInteger.ZERO
                    : value.equals(BigInteger.ONE) ? BigInteger.ONE
                    : value.equals(BigInteger.valueOf(2)) ? BigInteger.ONE
                    : Program.fibonacci.apply(value.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).add(Program.fibonacci.apply(value.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(2))))
    ); // Removed memoized() from here
```

And called

```
fibonacci.memoized().apply(BigInteger.valueOf(1000));
```

It takes very long as if `memoized()` was not applied.

What might be the reason for that?

Comment: Because a) the recursion isn't called on the memoized form, b) the whole point of memoizing is that you need to save the memoization, not create a new memoization each time.

Comment: I guess I got it. My Second example is memoized for only 1000. The other values are called on raw **fibonacci()**. Can you answer the question so that I accep it?

Comment: Why you don't use Binet's formula for calculating fibonacci?
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html

Comment: @SamirAghayarov I guess this is more about experimenting functional programming using Fibonacci as a toy example, rather than a genuine need for the function's values.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a) the recursion isn't called on the memoized form, b) the whole point of memoizing is that you need to save the memoization, not create a new memoization each time.

`Program.fibonacci` is defined in terms of itself, so the recursion calls that version, not the memoized version.